# add UIImageView subview as background to UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, subview

I am trying to add an UIImageView as a Subview to an existing UIImageView, to get a Backgroundimage, which can be set to AspectFit.

So I tried to do this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        photo.image = UIImage(named:"test.png")
        photo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        let width = self.photo.bounds.size.width
        let height = self.photo.bounds.size.height

        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:width,height:height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named:"DG.png")

        imageViewBackground.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        photo.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        photo.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }
}
```

But "DG.png" is always displayes in front of "test.png".
I also tried to insert the subview at index 0, and I've also tried to add that code in the extension of UIImageView, but nothing worked.

Can someone please explain me, why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: This code works fine with my both images are of same size. What is size of DG.png and test.png?

Comment: Hello, they are both 800x600 pixel. For me this code doesn't work. I always have the imageViewBackground on top.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a view as a subview of another view it will be always in front of the parent view.

why don't you use the first imageview for the background and add the photo as the subview?
and why are you adding the imageview in code ? you could just add the imageview in the storyboard.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer, it is more a question why it doesn't work this way, because I've found several infos on the internet, that this is the way to go, if you want to add a backgroundimage, where you need to set the aspect. 
If I add the ImageView in the storyboard, I can not set it as Subview of another ImageView, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In your case, `photo` has _only one_ subview `imageViewBackground`. The sendSubviewToBack method can only only rearrange the subview it contains. Since `photo` has only one subview, nothing happens.